# vuejs data updates but the change does not reflect in template

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js

This is my template

```
<template>
  <div class="array_bars">
    <div class="array_bar_wrapper">
        <div v-for="(h, index) in heights" :key="index" class="each_bar" v-bind:style="{ height: h + 'px' }"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="action-buttons">
        <button @click="resetArray">Reset</button>
        <button @click="bubbleSort">Bubble Sort</button>
        <button @click="sort">Sort</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here's the script

```
export default {
    name: 'SortingVisualizer',

    data() {
        return {
            heights: [],
            totalBars: 100,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getRandomInt(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        },

        resetArray() {
            this.heights = [];
            for(let i=0; i<this.totalBars; i++) {
                this.heights.push(this.getRandomInt(2, 400));
            }
        },

        bubbleSort() {
            for(let i=0; i<this.heights.length; i++) {
                for (let j=0; j<(this.heights.length-i-1); j++) {
                    if(this.heights[j]>this.heights[j+1]) {
                        let temp = this.heights[j];
                        this.heights[j] = this.heights[j+1];
                        this.heights[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(this.heights);
        },

        sort() {
            this.heights.sort((a, b) => a-b);
            console.log(this.heights);
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        for(let i=0; i<this.totalBars; i++) {
            this.heights.push(this.getRandomInt(2, 400));
        }
    },
}
```

when I click the `sort` button every thing works and changes is reflected in the template which uses the in built sort method.

But When I click the `bubbleSort` button the randomly generated heights get sorted(in the console) but the changes is not reflected in the template. Why?

Comment: You're running into one of the limits of reactivity with in vue. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) when changing values in the array.

```
Vue.set(this.heights, j, this.heights[j+1]);
Vue.set(this.heights, j+1, tmp);
```

Or copy the array, sort the copy and then assign it to `this.height`. This will also work.

Comment: It works now, btw the `i` should be `j+1` in this case

Comment: Thanks, changed it.